# IF Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how to design an excel function which will return a specified company name in a cell if any value at all is in the criteria cell.  I tried =IF(C3="<>",Microsoft,"") but this returns a blank cell whether there is data in C3 or not.  What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Mabye put quotes around Microsoft?  Like this "Microsoft"?

Answer (score 1):

Does `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C3)), "Microsoft", "")` do what you need it to do?